# How to fix: 'Cannot read property of undefined' of an object instance?

Tags: javascript, class, model-view-controller

I am trying to make a MVC pattern for a tinder clone (It's for a school project).

I can access the this.model and this.view in the constructor function but as soon as I try to execute a method outside of the constructor my variable seems to be "undefined".

It almost seems like that the this. variables go out of scope and get lost?

I have tried to log out the values in both the constructor and "likeUser" method, but only the constructor gives me the value, the other consolelog throws an error.

used plugins:
eslint

used compiler:
webpack

```js
import Event from './Event';
import View from '../view/View';
import Model from '../model/Model';

class Controller extends Event {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.view = new View(document);
    this.model = new Model(localStorage);

    // console.log(this.model)
    // console log will show the instance

    this.model.setToZero();
    this.model.checkFirstFetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10');

    this.profiles = this.model.selectProfiles();
    this.index = this.model.selectSwipeCounter();

    this.view.profile(this.profiles, this.index);

    this.listen('.select__likes', 'click', this.view.likes);
    this.listen('.select__dislikes', 'click', this.view.dislikes);

    //Event listener  will execute "likeUser()"
    this.listen('.btn__like', 'click', this.likeUser);
    this.listen('.btn__dislike', 'click', this.dislikeUser);
  }

  likeUser() {
    // console.log(this.model)
    // shows error 'Cannot read property 'selectProfiles' of undefined'

    console.log(this.model.selectProfiles());

    try {
      this.profiles = this.model.selectProfiles();
      this.index = this.model.selectSwipeCounter();
      this.model.addLike(this.profiles[this.index]);

      if (this.model.needNewUsers()) this.model.fetchProfiles();

      this.index += 1;
      this.model.setSwipeCounter(this.index);
      this.view.addLike(this.model.getArray('likes'));
      this.view.profile(this.profiles, this.index);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  }
}
```

I expect the function to return an array of profiles in the localStorage, instead it returns: 'Cannot read property 'selectProfiles' of undefined'

Comment: I think you need to bind the function in the constructor like this: this.likeUser.bind(this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.bind(this)` each time you call `likeUser()`

```
this.listen('.btn__like', 'click', this.likeUser.bind(this));
```

You can also try another approach to avoid having to `.bind` each time. Remove any instances of `.bind` and add this line after `super()`:

```
this.likeUser = this.likeUser.bind(this);
```

Do that for each function where you will need to share `this` with the constructor.

This method makes `this` be the same in the constructor and the binded function.

-

By the way, your `dislikeUser()` seems to be missing.

Comment: I tried what you proposed but it resulted in a "Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined" error

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the first line, I fixed it now.